# Hide string content in a span

Tags: android, spannable

I have `EditText` with content: `@<m id="36c03920-f411-4919-a175-a5b1eb616592">Full name</m>, how are you doing?`. I would like to hide tag with `id` from the user and keep only `@Full name, how are you doing?` when displaying text. Still `getText` should return full content.

I found `ReplacementSpan` useful to this approach. At first step, tried replacing only `</m>` but text is drawn twice in two lines. First line starts with `@` and second one starts with `<`. Also cannot insert new text. `getSize` is called multiple times and `draw` is called twice.

Is my approach correct? Should I try to found different solution and store ids in separate collection and do post processing on `getText()`?

Code:

```
    inner class RemoveTagSpan : ReplacementSpan() {
        private val regexEndTag = Regex("</m>")
        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
            text?.replace(regexEndTag, "")?.let { canvas.drawText(it, start, it.length - 1, x, y.toFloat(), paint) }
        }

        override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, fm: FontMetricsInt?): Int {
            return text?.replace(regexEndTag, "")?.let { paint.measureText(it).roundToInt() } ?: 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will give you exactly what you want, but generally displaying markup language in a TextView or EditText(?) can be done in this way:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("@<m id="36c03920-f411-4919-a175-a5b1eb616592">Full name</m>, how are you doing?", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("@<m id="36c03920-f411-4919-a175-a5b1eb616592">Full name</m>, how are you doing?"));
```

Comment: I am setting text using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`'s adapter so need to plug into `Tokenizer`'s `terminateToken`. That is why I would like to use `Spannable`. More over after using your solution `textView.text` returns `@Full name, how are you doing?` and then id is lost.